# If I grep recursivley through a directory, how can i save the resulting output to a simple .txt file?

Tags: linux, command-line, command-line-arguments, putty

So for example, if I used the command:

```
grep -r "search" *
```

could I use a command to save the resulting output to a .txt file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
grep -r "search" * > somefile.txt
```

This kind of redirection is not specific to the command you are running, by the way. It is a feature of the command shell.  The standard shell in linux is called bash.  `man bash` should give you more information than you probably want, but look for the section called REDIRECTION for a comprehensive discussion of these features.

Comment: @tehman you can use "> somefile" generally to redirect the output from stdout to a file. If you use >> instead of > you append to the given file

Comment: And if you use "2>&1" after the "> somefile" (or >>) you include the stderr (error messages) in the file as well.

Comment: awesome, thank you. Let's say that I finished one command, but wanted to append another command using >>. Would the command automatically break or show some sort of separation? And if not could I somehow show where one command ended and where another began?

Comment: @tehman No, there would be no separation in the output file unless you explicitly appended it.  For example by using the command "echo ======= >> somefile.txt" which would give you a short line of equals signs as a sort of separator line.

Comment: for clarification: assuming I already did one recursive search, and wanted to append another would the command be "grep -r "search" * echo ============>> somefile.txt"

Comment: @Peder Klingenberg: But I think a newline is being iserted at least

Comment: @das_weezul only if the command you run terminates its output with a newline.

Comment: @tehman: no.  You need to append the output of each command separately.  `grep -r search > somefile; echo ======== >> somefile; grep search2 >> somefile` would do it. (; is a command separator in bash)